# Unable to receive XMPP upstream messages after FCM migration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I have my XMPP server which was working with GCM. I upgraded to FCM as per google says though I am able to receive notifications from FCM notification console, not able to receive any upstream messages with FireBaseMessaging.send() ... If any one has done this migration please help.

Note : I have a XMPP server which was working and able to receive upstream messages via GCM. (After migration to FCM it is not receiving any messages even though the end points are changed. Am i missing anything from docs)

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed ! while using both (GCM, FCM) dependency in my project I was using a string resource default-project_id from GCM dependency. I now removed and replaced that with the project_id and it is fixed. So endpoint change is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the server endpoints. `Note that the new FCM version of gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/ is fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/ (without "http"):`

Change GCM endpoint

```
gcm-xmpp.googleapis.com
```

to FCM endpoint

```
fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com
```

source: [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints)

For more information, Check this [Upstream message syntax for FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#upstream) and how to send [Upstream messages on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#send_an_upstream_message_from_an_android_client_app).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I changed it though it is not a mandatory change.